# Visual SVN Server compression and cpu peak

Tags: apache, compression, visualsvn-server

I have a Visual SVN Server 3.2 x64 installed in Windows 2008 R2 Server x64.

I have less or more 50 projects with some huge binary files (eg.: 500 MB). After a commit with large change (difference/delta) on those huge binary files i have notice a cpu peak. The server has a bit of traffic (400 clients/hour) and is fully dedicated to Visual SVN Server (AWS EC2 large instance)

After a little investigation i think the problem is in the default compression of the default settings of Visual SVN Server.

Increase cache on delta doesn't help.

Visual SVN Server/subversion has a problem with compression large delta?

Disable it, when the delta between the commits is huge, is a best practice?

Other good suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, upgrade the server to the most recent version and see whether it helps. I'm pretty sure that the issue you've encountered has been already fixed. If the upgrade won't help, please drop us a line at support@visualsvn.com.

Upgrading from VisualSVN Server 3.2 to the latest 3.5 version should complete in less than 5 minutes. Please read [KB95: Upgrading to VisualSVN Server 3.5](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00095/) guide before beginning the upgrade.

You can get the latest VisualSVN Server installer at the [main download page](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/).

---

VisualSVN Server 3.2.x has reached **End of Support** in September, 2015. VisualSVN Server 3.2.x is not supported anymore and does not receive security and patch updates.

Please, keep your server instance up-to-date. We timely release maintenance updates for VisualSVN Server with security and bugfixes, and we strongly recommend our users to keep VisualSVN Server at the latest version. The list of fixed vulnerabilities is available for every release in [VisualSVN Server changelog](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/) and on our [release announcements page](https://www.visualsvn.com/company/news/).

Comment: Just for info: i have disabled the compression and all works